Bound on determinant when replacing columns
Suppose a square matrix $A$ has columns $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.
Construct $A'$ by replacing a column $a_k$ with $a_k'$ such that $||a_k - a_k'|| \le \epsilon$. Is it possible to bound $|\det A - \det A'|$?
I can imagine a bound like $n\epsilon$, but I'm not really sure how to prove it.

I am confused by your last sentence, so won't attempt an answer. But consider the case $n=2, k=1$ for the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\m&2m+1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A'= \begin{pmatrix} 1 +\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}& 2\m+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}&2m+1\end{pmatrix}$: I get the difference of the determinants to be $\frac{(2m-1)\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$
